# Does this edit not make the post more accurate and easier to read?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

I recently suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27386535) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704879/how-to-execute-onclick-and-href-both-in-an-anchot-tag-a). It was rejected by 2 reviewers with the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The edit looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

However, I believe that my edit

1. makes the question easier to find, since it fixed the misspelling of "anchor" in the question title.
2. makes the question easier to read due to the grammatical fixes.
3. makes the question more accurate by correcting the common mistake of writing `onclick` as `onClick` in HTML.

I also don't see any other issues with the question after my edit, so I fixed everything I could.

Can somebody help me figure out why this edit was rejected?

Comment: Why is `onclick` more correct than `onClick`? As far as I know, HTML is not case sensitive. And even if it would be a problem, you might change the behavior op is seeing by modifying their code.

Comment: Never ever ever ever modify code! That goes against the OP's question, and such edits are almost always rejected.

Comment: Using `onClick` instead won't cause the code to break, but `onclick` is a much more common convention. But that alone isn't quite enough of a reason to change it. A tiny issue is that `onClick` is usually seen with JSX, distinguished from `onclick` which is usually seen in HTML handlers. Could be slightly misleading at a glance. I think I'd do the same only with full edit privileges *and* when fixing other substantive problems with the post.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) I think this would fall under "don't change code conventions" since the original is valid even if it is unusual.

Comment: "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read[.]" Seriously? Although I agree it doesn't make it *significantly* easier to read, I really fail to understand how anyone could claim that it doesn't make it "even a little bit" easier to read. But then again, English is only my second language: perhaps native English speakers do use the word "Anchot" regularly.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I think a big reason is that you cannot reject an edit partially.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Usually when edits contain both good and bad changes, people tend to reject it.

Comment: @klutt: I understand, and I don't really oppose rejecting this edit. But the wording of the reason given for rejecting it is not really accurate in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things that would make me reject that edit:

1. HTML is case sensitive, but most browsers don't care if you put `onClick` instead of `onclick`. And if it was a problem, then you would be changing the meaning of the question since that may have been the problem in the first place.
2. The question already had proper grammar. It was easy enough to read for most people. Your grammar changes don't fix much.

For an edit to be approved, typically you need to fix any *wrong* grammar: wording that is stilted, typos in grammar <sub>not in code</sub> and fixing formatting.

As for the title, again. The grammar was okay before your edit. It was certainly readable, and anyone reading the question would certainly understand what it said. Your edit changed the wording of the question, even though the wording was perfectly acceptable in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, HTML tag and attribute names are case-insensitive according to the documentation: https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/documents.html#case-insensitivity ... I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Yeah... the only real fix that was "ideas" to "idea", which wouldn't have warranted an edit on its own.

Comment: @zooop98. Agreed. Unfortunately, not everyone knows that the W3C recently renamed the "a" element the "Anchot" element, that English now has adopted the German convention of capitalising all nouns, and that questions are no longer allowed to end with question marks.

Comment: @zcoop98 Also, it's a bit more relaxed when you get 2k rep. Then then edits don't end up in an edit review queue. That queue affects in two ways. One is that some higher rep users need to spend a little time examining your edit when it comes into the queue, and it also partially blocks from further edits until your edit is either approved or rejected. When you have more than 2k rep, you can do more minor edits.

Comment: @hb20007 It's okay. We all make mistakes from time to time... as a matter of fact, I have suggested a lot of edits that got rejected due to not making enough of a change.

Comment: @hb20007 The comment I wrote to zcoop98 was targeted to you. I just tagged wrong user.

Comment: It seems that this Meta SE question brought more attention to the post I tried to edit. Now I see that someone has fixed the "Anchot" typo, which, I guess, was the major issue.

Comment: @hb20007 it is best not to make assumptions on Stack Overflow, the site is busy enough to always prove you wrong. It is just as likely and probably even more likely that the editor never visits meta and simply came across it naturally. There are far more active participants on SO than there are on MSO. Heck, I'll bet there are far more people following the javascript tag than there are active participants on MSO.

Comment: @Gimby That's a possibility. However, if you consider that the last edit was in February 2014, it seems very unlikely that the next edit just happened to be when I posted this question.

Comment: @hb20007 It's very common that you draw attention by posting here at meta. It's actually has it's own name. We call it the "meta effect"